# MS ACCESS table default value code line for autogenerated sequential and unique alphanumeric number

Tags: format, default-value, ms-access-2016, auto-generate, sequential-number

I am new to MS Access and I would like to **generate an autogenerated sequential and unique alphanumeric number** of the format SYYMM001, SYYMM002, SYYMM003... (ex for 2023 january: S2301001, S2301002, S2301003).

I use **MS Access 2016**.

I am in my table, in View mode, in the column InvoiceCode in which I want the number to appear, in the general sheet, in Default Value I used the following code:

= "S" & Format(Now(),"yymm") & Format((DCount("[InvoiceID]","InvoiceTable")),"000")
where InvoiceID is the autonumber column and InvoiceTable the name of the table.

This code does not work and generate the following error:
"Unknown function "Dcount" in validation expression or default value on "Invoice Table.InvoiceCode"

I tried another code that I found online which works but instead of giving me a sequential number it generate a random number ex S2301586, S2301236 ...

="S" & Format(Now(),"yymm") & Format(Int(Rnd()*1000),"000")

Would you have a code that would do what I need?
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can't set this in the table.

You could try this in your form you use for data entry - in the **BeforeInsert** event of the form:

```
Me!InvoiceID.Value = "S" & Format(Date,"yymm") & Format(DCount("*","InvoiceTable"),"000")
```